# Como compactar arquivos em vários arquivos com tamanhos especificos?

Tags: c#

Tenho vários arquivos em uma pasta, estes arquivos já são arquivos .zip, .7zip, .rar...

Para facilitar o trabalho de manuseio destes arquivos, queria dividi-los em arquivos menores usando c#.

Existe alguma forma de dividir estes arquivos em arquivos menores, sem precisar descompacta-los com alguma função ou pacote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizando a biblioteca Ionic.Zip é possível fazer isso.
Porém você irá criar novos arquivos compactos contendo seus arquivos compactados.

```
public static void ComprimirEmPartes(string diretorio, string arquivoSaida)
{
    using (var zip = new ZipFile())
    {
        //Serão compactados novamente todos os arquivos dessa pasta
        zip.AddDirectory(diretorio);

        //Serão gerados arquivos com no máximo 5MB
        zip.MaxOutputSegmentSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024; // 5MB
        zip.Save(arquivoSaida);

        //TO DO: Aqui você poderia ir apagando os arquivos já processados.
    }
}

public static void ExtrairTudo(string arquivoZip, string diretorioSaida)
{
    using (var z = ZipFile.Read(arquivoZip))
    {
        z.ExtractAll(diretorioSaida);
    }
}
```